# ParseError thrown with message "syntax error, unexpected token "use setasign\Fpdi"

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

I'm using fpi and fpdf library

I'm not able to import these libraries

My php is: 8.1.5

fpdf: 1.84
fpdi: 2.0
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eneLl.png)

Comment: Don't you see that `use` is not allowed inside a function?

Comment: no, that's why i asked the question!